# Best way to pass server side configuration data to client side Angular's $rootScope

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

So I have a basic web app with server side authentication.  Then there is a front end angular framework used for the UI that is driven by directives and angular service factories.

This angular framework needs to know things about the current page request.

- Is the user authenticated
- Who is the authenticated user
- What are their authentication roles

Etc.

This is common data on every request.

I am trying to figure out the best way to provide that server side information to the front side angular framework.

At first I thought I would just put it in an HTTP Header, but you can't access HTTP Headers in javascript without making an additional ajax request and then basing the whole app off a chain from that initial ajax request.

The data is known during the response of the initial page request, so I would like to provide it with that response.

I know I can do it with a Hidden Field in the Head Tag, but that seems quite hacky to me and I'd ideally like to shy away from that.

The only other thing I can think of is to use a Global Action filter, and try to inject javascript into the response to initialize the framework context.

E.g. I could move the manual angular bootstrap code to be dynamic server side code that I inject into the end of the response (last script to run) and dynamically generate the angular.module(...).run function and then inject my global page data into $rootScope that way.

Edit: I could also use a cookie in the initial response which would be there when the script runs.

Are there any better ways of doing this, or maybe new features in MVC-6 to solve this problem?

Comment: I'd store all that information in the browser's local storage. One of the problems when using `$rootScope` is that you'll lose everything if the user navigates to another page.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot about Local Storage.  That seems like a good solution since Local Storage is only read client side and isn't resent to the server.  Which is why I wanted to avoid cookies.

Comment: Also if they navigate to another page it will reload from local storage, since navigation to another page will cause all the scripts to reload since I'm not using angular routing.  I've also got the entire app compressed into 1 js file in production mode.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think I can set local storage from server side.  I know I can't read it, but I was hoping I could add to it (write only) in the reponse, but doesn't appear to be possible.  So I'm back to dynamic JS, hidden fields, or 2nd ajax request.

Comment: You can't store on browser's local storage from the server. Reading and writing on local storage is responsability of the client, in your case, the browser, i.e. JavaScript.

Comment: Yeah, this is what I've gathered, so it seems the other 3 ways is the only way to get server side data surfaced for use in a javascript heavy client via the original page request (not making an additional ajax request to get it).

Answer (score 0):

## Temporary Answer unless someone finds a better way.

I created a Global Action Filter in MVC 6 om ASP.Net Core 1.0 that runs after any action executes, but before the view is processed for said action.  I use this to build an anonymous object of all the data I want to service to my front end JS Api.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ihq.moth.common.Filters
{
    public class ApiInjectFilter : IActionFilter
    {
        public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)                
        {
            ///This Code is used to setup json data in a the ViewData Dictionary used by the client side script API, like knowing who the current user is, if they are authenticated, what permissions they have etc (of course the permissions are only used for cosmetic nice haves, permissions are double checked server side).
            var isAuthenticated = context.HttpContext.User != null && context.HttpContext.User.Identity != null && context.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
            var initData = new
            {
                isAuthenticated = isAuthenticated
                //TODO Add User Later                
            };

            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(initData);
            var controller = context.Controller as Controller;

            controller.ViewData["APP_API_INIT_JS"] = json;
        }

        public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

### Then you need to configure it in your Startup.cs Configure Services Method...

```
   //Configure Services

   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddMvc(options => {
            options.Filters.Add(typeof(common.Filters.ApiInjectFilter), 0);       //My Filter is added here with order 0 (first)
        });  
        .......
   }
```

On each controller action request (what drives my entire app, traditional MVC get's etc) this APIFilter will run and add the javascript InitData (basically a javascript object (raw, not json)) to the ViewEngine's ViewData Dictioary.  This will make it available in the context of any View.

### Then I created a partial View to dynamically build the base namespace for my app and load this initialization Javascript from the view bag.

```
@{
    Layout = null;
    var initJsCode = this.ViewData["APP_API_INIT_JS"]; //this is the javascript generated in the Global Action Filter further above that runs after every action, and will contain Page Request Object data in javascript that every page shares (like authentication data and service end point urls etc.

}
<script>
    var moth = moth || (function () {
        return new function () {
            this.getInitData = function () {
                return @Html.Raw(initJsCode);
            }
        }
    })();
</script>
```

### Then I modified my _Layout.Cshtml file to use this partial view: Notice the partial view is called in two places, because one environment block is for development mode and the other is for production.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - Meower Of The Hour</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.min.css" asp-append-version="true" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mainWrapper" class="container-fluid">
        @{ Html.RenderPartial("Navbar");}
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
    <environment names="Development">
        <script src="~/js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/angular-messages.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/bootstrap.js"></script>        
        @Html.Partial("_InitJSData") //load my namespace with the getInitData method in it
        <script asp-src-include="~/js/app.js"></script>
        <script asp-src-include="~/js/services/*.js"></script>
        <script asp-src-include="~/js/directives/*.js"></script>
        <script asp-src-include="~/js/controllers/*.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/appLast.js"></script>
    </environment>
    <environment names="Production">
        @Html.Partial("_InitJSData") //load my namespace with the getInitData method in it
        <script src="~/js/scripts.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    </environment>
</body>
</html>
```

### And finally, the angular JS code that puts it on the rootScope object and removes the global variable for appJsonInitData (which resides in app.js) and loads after the _InitJSData Partial View;

```
(function(){
    var app = angular.module('moth', [])
    .run(['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
        $rootScope.appData = moth.getInitData(); //moth.getInitData is from the partial view above that was made dynamically and will be different for every request.
    }]);
})();
```

## Final Thoughts

This is the best way I've come up with to do this yet that doesn't use cookies or require an ajax request after page load to get it.  Keep in mind that when I'm done there will be a good bit more data coming back from getInitData.  It will contain context based information used all over the API that is specific to each request.